Can I bring eye drops into Japan?
My uncle asked me to carry the eye drop that his sister bought for him from the Philippines. It’s a flourometholone acetate. The contents are benzalkonium, flourometholone acetate, and purified water. It’s an anti-inflammatory eye drop from over the counter. Will I be able to carry this to Japan? I know Japan is very strict against drugs.

https://www.mhlw.go.jp/english/policy/health-medical/pharmaceuticals/01.html

Isn't something like that available in Japan as well?

Assuming your eye drops are not narcotics, and to my admittedly untrained eye the ingredients don't look like they are, it's fine to bring up to 2 months' worth of personal medicines to Japan. It's always worth bringing the prescription along just in case.
Any horror stories you've heard involve medicines on the Controlled Substances List (PDF), which are treated like illegal drugs if you don't have the appropriate paper sorted out.

Relevant: Not all controlled substances are allowed in Japan, even with "appropriate paper": https://www.incb.org/documents/Travellers/files/JPN_ENG_2014.pdf, notably stimulants (adhd meds) and cannabis.

I see no problem bringing those eyedrops to Japan. However, you might want to avoid mentioning that they're for your uncle. The regulations state that you can bring a two-month supply of medication for personal use. Simply say the eyedrops are for you.

Never lie to customs and immigration officers. Best also not tell people they have to lie.

You're absolutely right, @Willeke. My initial advice was misguided and potentially dangerous. Lying to customs officials is never a good idea and can lead to serious consequences. I should've thought that through more carefully before commenting. It's always best to be honest and follow the rules when traveling internationally.
